# Map a rectangle to another, including rotation

Tags: java, image-processing, affinetransform

I have two images, a *template*, and a *scan* page.
I print the template and then scan it.
The images have a point for each angle.
Because the scan could be translated, rotated and can have a different size (in vertical an horizontal, because of the printer distorsions) I have to map the four point of the scan to the template.
I have the position of each point.
How can I do it in Java to create an AffineTransform to apply to the scan?

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can find the affine transformation yourself mathematically and then apply it by your self using some loop that finds the source pixels for every destination pixel and doing some interpolation between them, but it really a waste of time.

There are many image processing library that will help you with that, like OpenCv.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way!
It's a bit confusing, but i hope this coud help someone.
referenceMarker1..4 are the *template* markers point 
translatedMarker1..4 are the *scan* markers point

The referenceMarker3 and translatedMarker3 are not used, an enanchement could be done.

```
final double translationX = translatedMarker1.getX() - referenceMarker1.getX();
final double translationY = translatedMarker1.getY() - referenceMarker1.getY();

// Calculate translation, rotation and scaling of the sheet
final double originalDx = referenceMarker2.getX() - referenceMarker1.getX();         // X distance between reference markers
final double originalDy = referenceMarker2.getY() - referenceMarker1.getY();         // Y distance between reference markers
final double translatedDx = translatedMarker2.getX() - translatedMarker1.getX();     // X distance between translated markers
final double translatedDy = translatedMarker2.getY() - translatedMarker1.getY();     // Y distance between translated markers

final double angle = Math.atan2(translatedDy, translatedDx) - Math.atan2(originalDy, originalDx);
double scaleX = Math.sqrt(originalDx * originalDx + originalDy * originalDy) / Math.sqrt(translatedDx * translatedDx + translatedDy * translatedDy);

final double originalDx4_2 = referenceMarker4.getX() - referenceMarker2.getX();
final double originalDy4_2 = referenceMarker4.getY() - referenceMarker2.getY();
final double translatedDx4_2 = translatedMarker4.getX() - translatedMarker2.getX();
final double translatedDy4_2 = translatedMarker4.getY() - translatedMarker2.getY();

double scaleY = Math.sqrt(originalDx4_2 * originalDx4_2 + originalDy4_2 * originalDy4_2) / Math.sqrt(translatedDx4_2 * translatedDx4_2 + translatedDy4_2 * translatedDy4_2);

// Generate a transformation matrix
// Translate back
transformation.translate(referenceMarker1.getX() - translationX, referenceMarker1.getY() - translationY);

// Scale
transformation.scale(scaleX, scaleY);

// Rotate
transformation.rotate(-angle);

// Translate first marker to origin to rotate around that point
transformation.translate(-referenceMarker1.getX(), -referenceMarker1.getY());
```